# Query has_many associations - Ecto, Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to query all of the leagues that belong to a particular user in my system.

The data setup looks like this:

#### USER MODEL:

```
has_many :users_leagues, Statcasters.UsersLeagues
has_many :leagues, through: [:users_leagues, :league]
```

So you can see, I have a has_many through association for users and leagues.

I'm trying to get a list of all the leagues a user has attached to it.

In rails it would look something like this: `user.leagues` and it would load up all of the leagues that have the current user id attached to it.

How can I do this with Ecto, Elixir and Phoenix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either preload `leagues` into `user` using `Repo.preload`:

```
user = user |> Repo.preload([:leagues])
# user.leagues is now a list of leagues
```

or use `assoc` and `Repo.all` to get a list of leagues for the user:

```
leagues = Ecto.assoc(user, :leagues) |> Repo.all
```

Comment: Awesome. That is easy!